# MYSQL Select and joining the results

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

Hi I am working on a search for a little system that we use in work. The systems uses 3 tables, quotes, jobs and details. within these tables there are several fields but th eone im focusing on are as follows:

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d27b/1) for my table and mysql statement

**Quotes**

- quote_id
- quotes_title

**Jobs**

- job_id
- job_quoteid - *job_quoteid stores the id of a quote which the job is realted to*

**Details**

- details_id
- details_line
- details_quoteid - *details_quoteid stores the id of a quote which the detail relates too, there can be several details linked to the quote*

My search is then to look at each of the tables based on my search term that is typed in and display the quote_id, job_id, quote_title and details_line.

here is the code i have currently for my search:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotes AS qts 
                      LEFT JOIN jobs AS jbs ON qts.quote_id=jbs.job_quoteid
                      JOIN details AS dts ON qts.quote_id=dts.quote_detailsid

                      WHERE concat(' ',qts.quote_code,qts.quote_id) like '%$param%'
                      OR qts.quote_title REGEXP '^$param'

                      OR concat(' ',jbs.job_code,jbs.job_id) like '%$param%'

                      OR dts.details_line LIKE '%$param%'
                     ");

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $fetch ) ) {
    $sResults .= '<tr id="'. $row->job_id . '">';
    $sResults .= '<td><a href="../../jobs.php?action=viewJob&amp;job_id='. $row->job_id .'">'. $row->job_code . $row->job_id .'</a></td>';
    $sResults .= '<td><a href="../../quotes.php?action=viewQuote&amp;quote_id='. $row->quote_id .'">' . 'Q' . $row->quote_id . '</a></td>';
    $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->quote_title . '</td>';
    $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->details_line . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Now this is where I need some further assistants, the search works, but for example if i was to type in "NCR" as a search term it will show 4 results, this is because I have a quote_title of "NCR Sets" and this quote has 4 detail_line attahced to it (these detail_line dont contain the words NCR) but obvioulsy its displaying 4 because it has found that the quote_id that contains the word "NCR" is in each of those. My results page therefore has the 4 results each in a table row with the quote_id, job_id, job_title and detail_line being diplayed, what I would like it to look is to have the 4 details display under one job_id and quote_id. If i was to code the table manually I would do somehting like the following to give you an idea:

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>quote_id</td>
    <td>job_id</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>quote_title</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>details_line</td>
    <td>details_line</td>
    <td>details_line</td>
    <td>details_line</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I hope this makes sense and some one can push me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Ian

Comment: create an sqlfiddle.

Comment: Added a link to a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do that could be to store the all outputs from the query, i.e. `$row->job_id`, `$row->quote_id` and so on in an array (or a variable) and check to see if the next `job_id` or `quote_id` is unique. To do this, you can use the [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

You can then set up an `if` statement to append a `td` inside the existing `tr` if the new `id` already exists or else just add a new `tr`.

> I could try and write a working code for it should you wish for it. For that, a Fiddle would be easy!

Comment: HI thanks, for the reply. Would that be with array_unique?

Comment: No. `array_unique` gives you a new array of just unique values. You don't want that! What you want is to just check if the new value already exists - a Boolean output - and apply conditional statement(s) accordingly.

Use `in_array()` function to check if the new `id` already exists in the saved array of all results. That should work!

[See the official Documentation of in_array here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). I have also edited my answer to include this.

Comment: Ok, and then would I not have to combine/add the details to get one array with it all in? It been a long day my brain is fried right now :(

Comment: Just create a few arrays - one for `$row->job_id` and the other for `$row->quote_id` and so on. Now only check the new output with the specific array it corresponds to. For example, you could check `if(in_array($row->job_id, $arr_job)) { //append to <tr> } else { //add new <tr> }`

Comment: @snookian And if your brain is fried, close all tabs, shut down the computer, take a chilled beer (assuming you are over 21) and relax. And work on it tomorrow! :)

Comment: I wish i could relax and grab a beer, schedule wont allow if :(. I couldnt be a pain and get you to write soemthign out for me, dont worry if you can't.

Comment: I would love to write a code and test it out for you, but it might take a few hours. Not free right now. Will try to do as soon as I can!

Comment: I have marked you answer as correct, I have probably don't it in a very crude way but I have somethign working based around the help you gave me. Thank you. I didnt use in_array() I just used if statements to check if line had the search term in else go to the next one.

Comment: Glad you could work it out. Sorry I couldn't find time to write a code for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this hope this might help.

```
SELECT * FROM quotes AS qts 
Inner JOIN jobs AS jbs ON qts.quote_id=jbs.job_quoteid
Inner JOIN details AS dts ON qts.quote_id=dts.quote_detailsid

WHERE concat(' ',qts.quote_code,qts.quote_id) like '%NCR Sets%'
OR qts.quote_title REGEXP '^NCR Sets'

OR concat(' ',jbs.job_code,jbs.job_id) like '%NCR Sets%'

OR dts.details_line LIKE '%NCR Sets%'

group by qts.quote_id
```

Comment: Will this not just show 1 result? I need to still have the 4 details displayed just under one quote id